# Does Node.js support Map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

[Apparently ECMA 6 supports an actual map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Is this available in Node.js yet? I have a situation where I actually need a map, not simply an associate array or POJO. Searching npm I wasn't able to find any equivalent.

Comment: Try running Node.js with the `--harmony` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a polyfill I found on npm: https://github.com/medikoo/es6-map

Is that what you were looking for?

Alternatively doing `node -h` will give you a bunch of experimental flags to enable Harmony support, which is currently only partially available (`node --harmony` to enable most of it)